# How can I change the position and size of an image in Apple pages 5.5?

Tags: pages, graphics, display

How can I change the position and size of an image in Apple pages 5.5? I have tried all the things I used to do but now when I import a photo, the handle bars do not show up, nor does the image editor as it used to do when clicking on the image.

Answer (score 1):

The photo must be selectable and selected for you to be able to manipulate it.
If the image is locked, unlock it with ⌥⌘L.

[image]

Comment: This works for me if the photo is directly on the page but not if it is inside a table cell. When it is in a cell, I can select, copy and cut it but it is not locked and cannot be manipulated.The cell itself as well as the table and row are also unlocked.

Comment: @Blah Yes, then the table cell itself defines the positioning of the image, it's no longer able to be directly manipulated by you. If you want to be able to move the image independently of the table cell, place the image on the page.